# StackPanel in StatusBar won't stretch

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, statusbar, stackpanel

When I add StackPanel to the StatusBar as last StatusBarItem it won't fill up all additional space. I wonder why is that since StatusBar internally uses DockPanel as ItemsPanel.

Here's a sample code:

```
<Window x:Class="Foo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Zadatak1"
    Title="MainWindow"
    WindowState="Maximized">
<DockPanel>
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="SkyBlue">
            <Label>Status....</Label>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label>Time:</Label>
                <Label>02:48:AM</Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```

If I change the order of the elements so Label is first and StackPanel is second, it fills additional space as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the red `StatusBarItem` that doesn't fill the space since you set its `HorizontalAlignment` property to `Right`. Change it to the default value of `Stretch` if you want it to fill the `DockPanel`.

The `StackPanel` does fill the `StatusBarItem` as expected.

Comment: So if it ain't "Stretch" it won't fill up all available space even if it is the last child of the DockPanel? I always thought that last child will fill all remaining space no matter what.

Comment: Obviously not. Remove HorizontalAlignment="Right" and you will see.

Comment: Yes, I've tried and it works, just surprised that it works that way. Thanks.